# Failed to compile ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Any and all help would be appreciated! I continue to get this and other errors involving firestore() not being function, etc. I'm not sure how to fix this, I created a to-do react app with firebase and had no issues and a week later I'm receiving errors on any firebase project I create.

I've tried doing import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app' with other imports for firestore, auth, and storage with no luck. I've also tried importing initializeApp from 'firebase/app', although I'm not 100% sure if I've done that correctly.

Currently my firebase.js file looks like:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  ...
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();
const storage = firebase.storage();

export { db, auth, storage };
```

I am doing import { db } from './firebase' in my app.js file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `v9.0.0+` installed, then change your import to compat version:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
// import "firebase/compat/[SERVICE_NAME]"
```

I'd recommend checking out the new [Modular SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#get_the_version_9_sdk) which has certain performance benefits. You can checkout this [Firecast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQvOAnNvcNQ) to learn more about the new SDK. The new syntax looks like:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
  ...
});

const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);

export { db, auth, storage };
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I reformatted it to match what you gave me. I'm no longer receiving the above error, but I'm now getting:   ```TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.db.collection is not a function``` in my App.js file where I access the database. I used `import { db } from './firebase';` Then in a useEffect hook used db.collection('posts') ... etc. I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: @DanShawl if you changed your syntax to modular one then you would have to write complete code in `modular` syntax. If you wish to use existing syntax then use compat libraries. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) has examples of both the syntaxes.

Comment: I cant seem to figure out how to access the information from my database. I changed my syntax to modular and havent gotten any errors, but it keeps returning undefined. I've also tried to use the import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app' with no luck. Im trying to replicate this code but with the new modular syntax:  `useEffect(() => {
  db.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    setPosts(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
  });
}, []); `

Comment: @DanShawl that's a completely different question. I'd recommend you to [post a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that. )

Comment: I currently have: `useEffect(() => {
    const helper = async () => {
      const docRef = collection(db, 'posts');
      const docSnap = await getDocs(docRef);
      console.log(docSnap.data);
    };
    helper();
  }, []);` Thank you for all the help. I'm really quite stuck and not sure what to do with this. I dont know why I still get the "Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase'" error with the compat imports and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: sorry I didnt see your reply just now. Do you have any insight into why I would still be getting the same "Module not found: Can't resolve 'firebase'" even with the compat imports?